# Mongo { current_tracking_number: null } duplicate key error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm getting this mongo duplicate key error when the following code executes. Basically, it creates a new **storeAdmin** document and saves it. After that, it creates a new **restaurant** document and assigns the previously created store admin's id to the **storeAdminID** field.

When the restaurant collection is empty it executes without throwing an error. But when there is at least one document it gives me the above error. There is no field called **current_tracking_number** in any of my schemas.

```
// create a new  store admin
const newStoreAdmin = new StoreAdmin({
  ...userData,
});

await newStoreAdmin.save();

// create a new restaurant for the store admin
const restaurant = new Restaurant({
  storeAdminID: newStoreAdmin._id,
});

await restaurant.save();

// assign the newly created store admins id to the restaurant document

newStoreAdmin.restaurantID = restaurant._id;
await newStoreAdmin.save();
```

Comment: Could you provide yours schemas, it like you have `current_tracking_number` as unique and you are always saving it as null value.

Comment: @LuisMartinez Don't know how and why but the problem was fixed after dropping both the collections from DB.

Comment: When you drop the collections all the index goes too.

Comment: @LuisMartinez Yeah, If the problem were in my schema or the code, it wouldn't be able to create more than one restaurant this time either...right? But now I can add as many documents